# Hiding controller name from URL

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

This question is in regard to the newest stable release of ASP.Net Core.

Just like previously asked questions I've browsed on StackOverflow, what I'm trying to accomplish is, when visiting any other view other than `Index` in the `Home` Views folder, and for example, visiting `About`, the URL reading:

```
www.example.com/About
```

and not: `www.example.com/Home/About`

**My code:**

In a newly started ASP.Net Core App, in the `Startup.cs` file, there's a Configure function:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**Things I've tried:**

I've tried changing the the routes to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "",
    new { action = Index, controller = Home }
);
```

Didn't work. I've also tried inserting this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "OnlyAction",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } 
);
```

But unfortunately, ASP.Net doesn't recognize the `IgnoreRoute` function yet.

Anyone else running into this with Core? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't force tags into the question title: stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: @Tseng, going forward, I will refrain, thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Asp.Net Core [Routing](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html#routing) documentation

Something like the following should allow for what you described

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "root",
    template: "{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```